# AFNetwork, Magical Record and block save within block

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking to fetch remote data, and Magical Record to import and save it locally.

Basically, I'm calling magical record save with a block, within the completion block from the AFNetworking method, which leads to my Unit Tests hanging forever.

Here's the code of the sync method. It is defined in a SyncEngine class, used as a singleton.

```
NSArray *operations = … ; // An array of AFHTTPRequestOperation defined before
__block BOOL syncSuccess = … ; // Set by operations
__block NSDictionary *syncErrors = … ; // Set by operations

NSArray *batchedOperations =
    [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:operations
                                         progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
                                             // …
                                         }
                                       completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
                                           NSMutableDictionary *allErrors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:syncErrors];
                                           [_localContext saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
                                               if (!success && error)
                                                   allErrors[@"MR_saveToPersistentStore"] = error;
                                               syncCompletionBlock(syncSuccess && success, allErrors);
                                           }];
                                       }
     ];

    // _manager is a AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
    [_manager.operationQueue addOperations:batchedOperations waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

So the issue comes from the fact that I'm calling "saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion" within "completionBlock".

If I use "saveToPersistentStoreAndWait" instead, it works but then I don't get to know if the save was successful or not.

What's the proper way to nest those operations ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AFNetworking 2.0, but won't that code potentially invoke save many times?

Wouldn't it be better to save once after completing all of the batchedOperations?

Comment: Not it won't, progressBlock is called after each operation, but completionBlock is called once after completing all of the batchedOperations.